# How do you uninstall / remove MarkLogic 7 on MacOS X?

Tags: database, macos, marklogic

Does anyone know how to completely remove MarkLogic 7 on MacOSX?

I've read their documentation which says:

> To entirely remove MarkLogic, remove the following directories:
>
> ~/Library/MarkLogic
>
> ~/Library/Application Support/MarkLogic
>
> ~/Library/StartupItems/MarkLogic
>
> ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MarkLogic.prefPane

But I **don't have those folders**.  I have no idea where it's been installed!

Then it says:

> To make Mac OS X completely forget it ever had a MarkLogic installation, run the following command from a terminal window:
>
> sudo pkgutil --forget com.marklogic.server

But that didn't seem to do anything.  I still have it in my System Preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that when you say you don't have those folders, you mean that you don't see ~/Library when you open Finder (please comment if that's not the case). You can make the Library directory appear by:

1. Open Finder
2. Click on your home directory
3. Click the Settings icon (gear)
4. Click Show View Options
5. Check the Show Library Folder option

Now you should be able to see the Library folder and you'll be able to remove those directories.

Note: I don't know your background, so forgive me if this is too basic, but the ~/Library directory contains a bunch of stuff that OS X uses to make your system run. It's hidden because making mistakes in there can cause problems that are tricky to fix. If the contents of ~/Library are not familiar to you, you might want to un-check that option when you're done.

Comment: Spot on Dave, thanks.  I was actually looking in the Library at the root level on the hard drive rather than the user.  Interestingly  I didn't have the 'Show Library Folder' option in the settings window.  But, I found that I could use the 'go' option from the finder menu and then hold the 'alt' key which showed the Library folder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dave is probably right. But just in case, you can use that prefpane to stop MarkLogic, then use the Error Log button to open the log. Start MarkLogic and the first new line in the log will tell you where it is:

```
Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 7.0-3 x86_64 in /Users/${USER}/Library/MarkLogic
          with data in /Users/${USER}/Library/Application Support/MarkLogic/Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't delete `~/Library/PreferencePanes/MarkLogic.prefPane`, but remove the preference pane by right-clicking on it in System Preferences. It will then be deleted, but you can't remove its icon from System Preferences if you have deleted the preference pane.